# OS X: Get mouse button position of button greater then the three standard buttons

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Is there an easy way to find out if a button on a multi-button mouse (has more then three buttons) is clicked?

e.g. the fifth button on a five button mouse.

I know it is possible, because apps like USB Overdrive and Smart Scroll do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, just ask for the event's `buttonNumber`:

```
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if(theEvent.type == NSOtherMouseDown)
    {
        NSLog(@"Button number %ld was pressed.", theEvent.buttonNumber);
    }
}
```